# How can i check the publication target for a given component?

Tags: core-service

I am retrieving components in a specified folder using Core Services to build an API to expose some content. We have a preview and live environment and I need to retrieve components that have been published to the "live" environment only

code being used for retrieving components:

```
private static void LoadExistingProducts()
{
    LinkToSchemaData[] schemaLinks = new[] {
        new LinkToSchemaData { 
            IdRef = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["productSchema"] 
        }
    };

    // Define a filter to return only Components.
    OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData componentFilter = new OrganizationalItemItemsFilterData
    {
        ItemTypes = new[] { ItemType.Component },
        BasedOnSchemas = schemaLinks
    };

    //get xml list of existing product components
    existingProducts = client.GetListXml(
                                    ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["productComponentFolder"],
                                    componentFilter);

    ComponentData component = null;
    XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Tridion_Product));

    foreach (XElement element in existingProducts.Elements())
    {
        component = (ComponentData)client.Read(element.Attribute("ID").Value, null);
        StringReader readr = new StringReader(component.Content);
        MyReader reader = new MyReader(readr);
        Tridion_Product product = serializer.Deserialize(reader) as Tridion_Product;
        //Place deserialized version of existing object in dictionary for comparison step
        ProductDictionary.Add(product.ProductID, product);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use either `IsPublished` or `GetListPublishInfo` methods in order to know if a given component is published to a given target or not.

Try this.

```cs
if (channel.IsPublished("[item id]", "[target id]", true)) {

}
```

or

```cs
PublishInfoData publishData = channel.GetListPublishInfo("[item id]")
                                     .Where(w => w.PublicationTarget.Title == "Your Target")
                                     .FirstOrDefault();
if (publishData != null) {

}
```