# Get list of target types to which a component is published

Tags: 2011, publishing, core-service

I am trying to  publish a page to a target based on a components publish details. If a component is published to a particular target type then i need to publish the page to the same target type. I am trying to achieve this using core services. I need to fetch the list of target types to which the component is published.how can i achieve this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried reading the API documentation already, look for `ICoreService2013.GetListPublishInfo()`

Comment: Also, take a look at answer here http://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/4339/how-can-i-check-the-publication-target-for-a-given-component/4340#4340